# Pygame: Tiled Map or Large Image

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to decide if it is better to use a pre-rendered large image for a scrolling map game or to render the tiles individual on screen each frame.  I have tried to program the game both ways and don't see any obvious difference in speed, but that might be due to my lack of experiences.

Besides for memory, is there a speed reasons to not use a pre-rendered map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason I can think of for picking one over the other on modern hardware (anything as fast and with as much ram as, say, an iPhone), would be technical ones that make the game code itself easier to follow.  There's not much performance wise to distinguish them.

One exception I can think of, is if you are using a truly massive background, and doing tile rendering in a GPU, tiles can be textures and you'll get a modest speed bump since you don't need to push much data between cpu and gpu per frame, and it'll use very little video ram.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think for now, I am going to stick with the pre-rendered map. To avoid the extra calculations to offset and then draw the tiles on scree.  My map images is only about 62kB.

Answer (score 1):

Memory and speed are closely related.  If your tile set fits in video memory, but the pre-rendered map doesn't, speed will suffer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it really depends of the map's size but this shouldn't be a problem even with a low-level-computer.

The problem with big images is that it takes a lot of time to redraw all the stuff on it so you will get an unflexible "map".

But a real advantage with an optimized image(use convert()-function and 16 bit) is are the fast blittings.

I work with big images as well on a maybe middle-good-computer and I have around 150 FPS by blitting huge images which require just ~ 100? MB RAM

```
image = image.convert()#video system has to be initialed
```

The following code creates an image(5000*5000), draws something on it, (blit this to the screen, fill the screen)*50 times and at the end it tells how long it took to do one blit and one flip.

```
def draw(dr,image,count,radius,r):
   for i in range(0,5000,5000//count):
      for j in range(0,5000,5000//count):
         dr.circle(image,(r.randint(0,255),r.randint(0,255),r.randint(0,255)),[i,j],radius,0)

def geschw_test(screen,image,p):
   t1 = p.time.get_ticks()
   screen.blit(image,(-100,-100))
   p.display.flip()
   return p.time.get_ticks() - t1

import pygame as p
import random as r

p.init()
image = p.Surface([5000,5000])
image.fill((255,255,255))
image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))
screen = p.display.set_mode([1440,900],p.SWSURFACE,16)
image = image.convert()#extremely efficient
screen.fill((70,200,70))
draw(p.draw,image,65,50,r)#draw on surface
zahler = 0
anz = 20
speed_arr = []
while zahler < anz:
   zahler += 1
   screen.fill((0,0,0))
   speed_arr.append(geschw_test(screen,image,p))
p.quit()
speed = 0
for i in speed_arr:
   speed += i
print(round(speed/anz,1),"miliseconds per blit with flip")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of the map you want to make, however, with the actual technologies it's very hard to see a tile-map "rendered" to take longer than expected, tiled based games are almost extinguished, however is always a good practice and a starting point to the world of game programming